# iPhone, why set alpha of navigation item will change self.view.frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

For some reasons I want to set my navigation items' alpha with panGesture.

And my view's height is larger than screen's height, eg screen height is 568 but I set my view's height to 668.

The code I change navigation items:

```
-(void)hideTopview:(CGFloat) alpha{

    alpha = (alpha - 64)/100;
    float adjustAlpha;
    if (alpha < 0) {
        alpha = 0;
    }
    if (alpha < 0.5) {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.rightBarItemSmall;
        self.navigationItem.titleView = self.naviShopName;
        self.naviShopName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30);
        self.naviShopName.alpha =0;
        self.naviRightViewSmall.alpha = 0;

        adjustAlpha = (alpha)/0.5;
        self.naviShopName.alpha =1 - adjustAlpha;
        self.naviRightViewSmall.alpha = 1 - adjustAlpha;

    }
    if(alpha > 0.5){
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.rightBarItemFull;
        self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;
        if (alpha>1) {
            adjustAlpha = 1;
        }
        else{
            adjustAlpha = (alpha - 0.5)/0.5;
        }
        self.naviRightViewFull.alpha = adjustAlpha;
    }

}
```

Before Run this code, the view frame height is 668, after run this code, it change to 568. I also trying to set frame in the function but not work.

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.size.height = self.superViewHeight;
self.view.frame = frame;
```

Comment: where are you calling the hideTopview ?

Comment: in UIPanGestureRecognizer selector, every time I scroll my view I want to recalculate the alpha of navigation items

Comment: like-(void)scrollSlideView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) panGesture{
[self hideTopview:self.slideMultiViewController.view.frame.origin.y];
}